# Is there exist a function having a property like exponential function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Is there a function deﬁned on all of $\mathbb{R}$ that is inﬁnitely often diﬀerentiable
and satisﬁes $f'''(x)= f(x)$ for all x, but not of the form $f(x) = ce^x$ for a real constant c?

Comment: You might try describing this problem via the method of undetermined coefficients.  You will find that any such result will be of the form $c_0a_0(x)+c_1a_1(x)+c_2a_2(x)+c_3a_3(x)$ where $a_k(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{4n+k}}{(4n+k)!}$.  See if you can figure out why that is and prove it yourself.  Common examples of such functions would be linear combinations of $\sin(x),\cos(x)$ as well as $e^x$.

Comment: Is that 4n or 3n?

Comment: I misread as having four hyphens instead of three.  The method and result described in my previous comment still applies, except they will instead be linear combinations of only three terms with $a_k=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{3n+k}}{(3n+k)!}$, unfortunately the common trig functions don't satisfy this anymore,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example is

$$f(x)=e^{\omega x}+e^{\omega^2 x},$$

where $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ is the principal cube root of unity.

Despite appearances, $f(x)$ is real whenever $x$ is real; using the fact that $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ are $0.5\pm \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i,$ we have

$$f(x)=2 e^{-x/2} \cos \big(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}x\big).$$

---

Moreover, you could actually take any linear combination

$$f(x)=ae^x+be^{\omega x}+ce^{\omega^2 x}$$

as a solution to the original problem. Another example that's real-valued on the reals would be $f(x)=-ie^{\omega x}+ie^{\omega^2 x}=2 e^{-x/2} \sin \big(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}x\big).$

Comment: your example is the complex-valued function. is there exist a real-valued function having this property?

Comment: @user52523 The function I gave *is* real-valued; I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your sharing.

Comment: You're welcome.